# Reading data from HDFS file and sending it to a kafka producer

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, kafka-producer-api

I have a set of files in HDFS, these files are tweets. I need to stream these tweets through kafka producer. Later, I need to process the stream and perform some analytics over it.

What I have done is:

a) Write a java program to read a file line by line from HDFS.

b) I can publish this message to a topic from a java program using kafka.

But, this is a very slow method. And the data sizes are large.

I looked at some mapreduce jobs from which I can feed data to the kafka producer, I am new to this and not very sure how to do that too.

Here is what I am talking about:
https://my-bigdata-blog.blogspot.com/2017/07/hadoop-custom-outputformat-hdfs-send-to-kafka.html

Comment: Not sure why you are looking at Mapredude and output formats... Spark/Flink/NiFi can do all this just fine.

Comment: You could also do `hadoop fs -cat file.txt | kafka-console-producer --topic x ...`

Comment: Yeah actually I have tried the 2nd option, hadoop fs -cat /somefile.txt, I was keeping that as a backup option in case I fail to find something. 

I wasn't aware of Flink, I'll check it out. If I'm correct you're saying using flink , we can read hdfs files and publish to a kafka topic isn't it?  @cricket_007

Comment: Apache Spark, Flink, and Beam share simlar concepts of reading from HDFS filesystem, yes. Personally, I prefer Nifi and Streamsets as it's more graphical

Comment: Why not ingest the tweets into Kafka directly, and then write them to HDFS as and when you need to?

Comment: Oh there’s a 1TB dataset that I need to stream and perform data preprocessing on. So the data is already there in Hdfs